# How to Set Read Only for Certain Lines in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I want to create custom file editor that disable certain line to edit in Visual Studio Code. For example (in go):

```
package main                                      <- read only
                                                  <- read only
func solution(x, y int) (res int) {               <- read only
  // user can edit here                           <- editable by user
                                                  <- editable by user
  return res                                      <- read only
}                                                 <- read only
                                                  <- read only
func main() {                                     <- read only
  solution(2, 3)                                  <- read only
}                                                 <- read only
```

Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is not possible. You can't control editing by line in a text file.

Comment: Would be a pretty fun editor to implement

Comment: If I understand your goal, a poor-man alternative is using two files. One file contains the main() and all ancillary code. The other file contains the solution() function and you explain to the user that the signature of solution() must stay the same and everything else can be edited...