Support for readonly lines in VS Code editor
I am working on a VS Code extension, I want to display an editor file with the first3 three lines as readonly and the remaining lines can be edited.
Is there an API that allows this behaviour?
Currently the workaround I have is using decorators (to specify which lines are readonly), and if the user makes changes to those lines I replace the three lines with the initial text using onDidChangeTextDocument().

I was going to answer this, and then searched for existing Q&A and found https://stackoverflow.com/q/65453980/11107541 and answered that instead. as soon as it can be used as a duplicate target, i intend to use it to close this question, unless you think your question is different or not covered by the answer I wrote there.

yeah that helps thanks. @starball

if my answer there helps, consider voting :)

I have a possible solution I will post soon.

I came up with this possible solution.  I am posting it here as the linked question in the comments above is much more problematic as the relevant lines could easily change and would require a lot more code to track that.  This question seeks to restrict the first three lines (of perhaps limited files?).

var global = Function('return this')();  // used for global.typeDisposable below
   // there may be a better solution for this: globalThis


async function activate(context) {
    
    // check the activeTextEditor on extension activation and run the extracted function from below
    
    vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(async event => {
        
        // check if it is the file(s) you are interested in
        if (event && vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName === 'c:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\TestMultiRoot\\test1.js') {
            
            // extract this to a separate function so can run it upon extension activation if the inital file
            // is the one you want to restrict          
            
            if (!!global.typeDispoable) return;
        
            global.typeDisposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('type', async arg => {
                
                // arg is the text trying to type
                if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.active.line >= 3) {    // on line 3+, lines are 0-based
                    vscode.commands.executeCommand('default:type', arg);  // type it
                }
                // else give the user some type of message cannot type here, hover/decoration/notification
            });
        }
        else if (event && !!global.typeDisposable)  await global.typeDisposable.dispose();  // not in the file test1.js
    });
}

So you will want to extract the inner workings of onDidChangeActiveTextEditor() above to a separate function so it can called immediately upon extension activation IF the current editor is the one you want to restrict.  onDidChangeActiveTextEditor() is not fired upon activation, so if the active editor is the file you want to restrict you will have to call the extracted function.
Also, the above code registers the type command.  It may be that vim/neoVim/etc. also do that and this code should be checked to see if it is compatible with vim or neoVim for example.  It is actually remarkable how little code is necessary to do what you want if using the type interception method demonstrated here.
I would also provide a command or a way in a hover or notification to actually enable typing in those first three lines (just in case).  The command/hover link could call global.typeDisposable.dispose().
And perhaps a setting that enables the "read-only" status of those lines, and you would check that setting before enabling the code shown above.  You have to get those lines into the file somehow initially - you could also check if the file is empty and if so don't enable this code.

Can you provide the full code for this? Not sure how this would work.

@XXDIL That is the full working code - although you should add some conveniences for the user.  And obviously I don't know what filenames or types you want this to apply to.  Have you run just this code?
